# Is there a way to make ASP page update in real time, like Ajax?

Tags: ajax, asp-classic

Is there a way to make ASP page update in real time, like Ajax?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll give you a brief summary of ASP & AJAX to help you understand the difference between these two technologies.

**ASP**

ASP is a server-side language. Like it's cousins: Python, Ruby, PHP. It is used to generate dynamic content on the server, and then pass it along as HTML to the client's browser. ASP cannot "update" anything in realtime, as it cannot connect to a client of it's own accord to make an update. Each update/response from your ASP server must be in response to a request from the client.

---

**AJAX**

AJAX stands for Asynchronous Javascript And XML. It is not a language in and of itself. The language here is Javascript, which is primarily a client-side language. AJAX functions by the javascript running on the client machine sending a "special" request (XMLHTTPRequest) to your server, and receiving a response. Javascript then uses this response to update the page dynamically.

---

That said, you should study up on both Javascript and ASP before you begin attempting to create something. AJAX is somewhat of an advanced topic. As mentioned previously http://asp.net/ajax is a good resource.

Answer (score 1):

Check [ajaxed](http://www.ajaxed.org) which is a free AJAX library for classic ASP. Many tutorials included.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET ajax:

[asp.net/ajax](http://www.asp.net/ajax/)
[wikipedia.org/wiki/asp.net_ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_AJAX)

Or for classic ASP:

[aspajax](http://www.aspajax.org/)

Answer (score -1):

yeah with ajax, you could simply use jQuery or even the Asp.Net Ajax Client Library, also there are other frameworks that will help you do this in a very simple way, or you could go the hard way and hand roll your own javascript to make the requests.

On jquery there are a number of methods such as $.post that allow you to make an asynchronous request to the server, just point it to the correct url and you will have the data you wish.

Answer (score -2):

Sure, with JavaScript and DOM, create a 1x1 IFRAME and make it load an asp page that will Response.Write whatever information in whatever simplest format you can parse with JavaScript. I did it back in 1999 way before AJAX was invented.